# Sorting a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a large nested dictionary that I need to sort and extract data from, but I am not sure how to approach the problem. Here is the `dict` form:

```
mydict = {Person 1 : [{'2017-06-02': {'Country A': {'City 1': {'Population': '0', 'Temp': '10'}}}, '2016-06-02': {'Country B': {'City 2' :{'Population':'1'}}}]
```

What method could I use to sort the list by date and be able to iterate through it afterwards?

Note: the actual dict has a lot more entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted to sort the dates of just that one person. I would use the `sorted` function with the `key` argument referring to the dictionary's key to return a list. I quickly changed your 'Person 1' key to a string for testing and just changed the nested dictionary to a string, it not important here.

```
mydict = {'Person 1' : [{'2018-11-02': "more_dicts"},
                        {'2017-06-02': "more_dicts_here"}]
         }


def get_key(input_dict):
    return input_dict.keys()  # Returns key of dictionary

# Printing the result
print sorted(mydict['Person 1'], key=get_key)

# Adjusting the value of Person 1 if necessary
mydict['Person 1'] = sorted(mydict['Person 1'], key=get_key)
```

If you want to do this for each person, you can use this method above and just loop through each key of the dictionary. You can also use `lambda` functions instead of the normal function defined here.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example if you wanted to loop through each person and using the `lambda` function (instead of defining a function like `get_key`)

```
mydict = {'Person 1' : [{'2018-11-02': "more_dicts"},
                            {'2017-06-02': "more_dicts_here"}],
          'Person 2' : [{'2019-11-02': "more_dicts"},
                            {'2017-06-02': "more_dicts_here"}],
          'Person 3' : [{'2018-11-02': "more_dicts"},
                            {'2020-06-02': "more_dicts_here"}]
         }

for person in mydict.keys():
    mydict[person] = sorted(mydict[person], key=lambda x: x.keys())

print mydict
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were searching for

```
mydict = {'Person 1' : [{'2017-06-02': {'Country A': {'City 1': {'Population': '0', 'Temp': '10'}}}, '2015-06-02': {'Country A': {'City 1': {'Population': '0', 'Temp': '10'}}}}]}

od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(mydict["Person 1"][0].items()))
```